# Add-Text Comments only in APEX Page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

On a Oracle Apex Detail Page, I have a readonly Text 
field which displays the Field Comments, which is read only.

I hava another Field "New Comment" , which is not bound to a Database Field.

If the Form has been saved successfully, i want that Contents 
of the non-bound Field is appednded to the readonly Field, with a timestamp in the header.

So I want to know whats the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own process which will update the `comment` column, e.g.

```
update your_table t set
  t.comment = to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') ||   --> timestamp
              chr(10)        ||                           --> new line
             :P1_NEW_COMMENT ||                           --> new comment first
              chr(10)        ||                           
              t.comment;                                  --> old comment
```

Comment: Or add a computation on submit, where you can modify any values of columns before the ARP executes.